# Pattern highlighting command

Tags: command-line, grep, highlighting

Folks, I want to know if there exists a command that just highlight some portions of the input text, rather than filtering it like `grep` does.

To give an example, suppose the following input text:

```
foo bar
gaz das
xar
```

`grep "bar\|gaz" input` would print the first two lines, highlighting `bar` and `gaz`, but would not display `xar`.

I'm aware that I could simply set a big constant to the `-C` argument, so it would "*always*" show the context, like: `grep -C1000 "bar\|gaz" input`, but I'm not sure if that is efficient, or if there is a better tool for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USE:

```
  egrep --color 'pattern|$' file
```

or if you want using grep

```
  grep --color -E 'pattern|$' file
```

"pattern|$" will match lines that have the pattern you're searching for AND lines that have an end -- that is, all of them. Because the end of a line isn't actually any characters, the colorized portion of the output will just be your pattern

Comment: `-E` is not needed, you can `grep --color 'pattern\|$' file`